# how to project specific properties from an embedded document which is a list mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

My `StudentEntity` looks as below

```
public class StudentEntity
{
  [BsonId]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  
  [BsonElement("name")]
  public string Name {get; set; }

   [BsonElement("addresses")]
  public List<AddressEntity> Addresses {get; set;}
}


 public class AddressEntity
{
  [BsonId]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  
  [BsonElement("city")]
  public string City {get; set; }

   [BsonElement("pinCode")]
  public string PinCode{get; set; }
  //& so on
}
```

Method to fetch the students looks as

```
public async Task<Student> GetStudent(string id)
{
  var filter = Builders<StudentEntity>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id == id);
  var projection = Builders<StudentEntity>.Projection
                   .Include(x => x.Name)
                   .Include(x => x.Addresses.Select(y => y.City); //#LOC

  var result = _studentsCollection.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<StudentEntity, StudentEntity>()
  {
    Projection = projection
  }
}
```

however, the projection definition at #LOC is throwing the below run time error

- [MongoDB Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28039274/mongodb-unable-to-determine-the-serialization-information-for-the-expression-err)

**My require is to only select some properties from the embedded document (array/list of address)**
?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try that by creating an Address entity with limited fields - and use it instead of the original Address entity - for this particular use case. The projection can be controlled by the limiting the properties in a class.

Comment: See this post with similar question: [Projection of mongodb subdocument using C# .NET driver 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29720783/projection-of-mongodb-subdocument-using-c-sharp-net-driver-2-0) and [Get array of partial model from sub document array (MongoDB C# Driver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968069/get-array-of-partial-model-from-sub-document-array-mongodb-c-sharp-driver).